# Dúvidas de mascaras Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Olá, sou novo em Angular e estou tendo problemas com mascara!
Estou utilizando as mascaras de: "Angular-input-mask";

tenho um formulário que possui um campo 'CPF', a mascará é aplicada perfeitamente. Visualmente quando eu digito uma letra, essa letra não aparece no campo, pois o campo 'CPF' aceita apenas números! Porem quando eu digito uma letra, essa letra fica armazenada com input, e minha validação do formGroup é ativada automaticamente. Gostaria de saber como faço para evitar isso!

Na foto abaixo, exibi o valor do meu form e dos campos do mesmo e digitei uma letra. Reparem que o campo 'CPF' está vazio, mas o valor do input está preenchido com a letra digitada..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do formulário...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: posta o codigo!

Comment: Código do formulário postado

Comment: tentat colocar um type="number"

Comment: e tira o ng model

Comment: Então, o type="number", não pode ser, porque se não a mascara não será aplicada, pois a mesma possui "..-", pontos e traço..
E o ngModel é da aplicação da mascara tbm, se tirar a mascara para de funcionar...

Comment: O problema e que vc esta misturando o reactive forms(formControlName) com o template forms(ngmodel). recomendo que vc faca sua própria mascara so procurar o regex de cpf.

Comment: Entendi! mas como faço essa mascara própria? Usando JQuery? Porque estava utilizando o do JQuery e estava dando o mesmo erro, por isso decidi trocar!! O regex faz mascara? ate então sei utilizar apenas para validação...

Comment: da uma olhada nessa resposta, vc cria sua diretiva de cpf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/input-mask-fields-in-angular2-forms

Comment: vc tbm pode procurar uma biblioteca que funcione com o formcontrolname

Comment: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme

Comment: Opah, encontrei o mesmo que você postou, vou fazer os testes aqui e já te aviso para marcarmos a resposta aqui! muito obrigado..

Comment: Opah, funcionou 100%, pode posta o link como resposta que confirmo aqui! muito obrigado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumindo o problema era que você estava misturando o reactive forms(formControlName) com o template forms(ngmodel). Neste caso ou você cria sua própria mascara ou procura outra [biblioteca que funcione com o reactive forms](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme).

Neste caso você so precisa procurar o regex de cpf e aplicar ao elemento.